# Cluttered junit logs, why does it repeat statements?

Tags: java, ant, junit, log4j, junit4

When I run my junit tests my logs look like:

```
[junit] Testcase: testSomething1 took 0.546 seconds
[junit] <statement 1>
[junit] <statement 2>
[junit] <statement 3>
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.265 sec
[junit] -----------------------Standard Output-----------------------------
[junit] <new statement 1>
[junit] <new statement 2>
[junit] <statement 1>
[junit] <statement 2>
[junit] <statement 3>
[junit] -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to remove the duplication of statements 1-3, but I do not know how.

Example Testcase:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { MyConfig.class})
public class MyTestClass
{
   @Autowired
   private ClassIWantToTest testee;

   @Test
   public void testCase1()
   {
      boolean bool = testee.callFunc1();
      Assert.assertTrue(bool);
   }
}
```

From this link, I see how to control this output in Gradle, but there has to be a way to control it with Spring or Junit itself right? [LINK](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/10/gradle-goodness-show-standard-out-or.html) I am beginning to think that I have been looking in the wrong place this whole time. Is there an ant setting that can hide the standard output and standard errors sections of the output in my console?

Comment: How are you configuring log4j within your JUnit tests?

Comment: I just added an example of what my test cases look like. I am not doing anything special to the logging, but I get all that extra output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is bizarre to me, but I need to to set showoutput="false" on my ant junit task. My formatter nested element gives me all the output I need. By having both showoutput="true" and a formatter nested element, I was having the output printed twice to my console :(

I figured this out from this stack overflow question: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621517/option-for-ant-junit-task-to-dump-console-output-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not intimately familiar with junit, but see if the log-level is unset. It may then default to DEBUG which means you'll get everything. If so, try changing the log-level to WARN.

Comment: I am not interested in masking the issue by changing my log level, I want to keep my logs from producing duplicate messages.

Comment: I see. With my current knowledge of Junit, I can't answer that.
If you can provide a fabricated test with code, I might be able to help you further.